# Is a child forbidden from seeing old baby pictures/videos of their parents where the parents might be naked?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

I forget the *mekor* (if anyone remembers that'd be great), but I remember learning that a child is not allowed to see their parent naked.
Not a parent yet myself, but our generation has lots of family videos and pictures of when we were young kids.

Does the *issur* of not seeing one's parents naked apply to old baby photos/ videos?

Comment: They weren’t your parents in the picture.

Comment: That's an interesting approach/ *hagdarah*

Comment: Asked R' Baruch Simon shlit"a from YU this question last week, he said he didn't think it would be a problem.

Comment: Would still love to hear the *svara* behind it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Pesachim (51) mentions the prohibition against going to the bathhouse with one's father, father-in-law, stepfather or brother-in-law see Rama in Even Ha'ezer (23).The reason for this prohibition is that seeing these relatives unclothed might lead to improper thoughts.
- http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1136

Comment: Right, so if that's the *svara* I would assume it wouldn't apply here- what child is going to have improper thoughts looking at their unclothed 2 year old parent?